# how get new instance of activity to back in android

Tags: android, android-activity

i develop app launch activity A with dialog theme by alarm manager and after 5 minutes it will be recalled but with new data .. currently the new instance it get on top of last

i want first instance to be on top and when second comes it go behind the first and when the third comes it go behind the second .. and so on

shortly, we can say i want to make something like a private stack for instances of this activity

how can i do that ??

this is my code i used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,FeedsDialogActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
intent.putExtra("fPageid", fpageid);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand, but you can call

```
protected void onRestart();
```

From the activity to update your UI or making a task instead of creating a new instance of it.

If your second activity comes after the first one (foreground), call :

```
finish();
```

Then, the first activity will be active again, and onRestart will be called.

Check the android activity life cycle :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

To do this using dialog activities, you'd need instance 1 change so that it displays the UI of instance 2, and make instance 2 show the ui from instance 1 - that is, you're not changing the back stack, you're changing what is displayed in the old activity. Alternatively, you could close the task back to a known activity (with the clear top flag) and relaunch the activities in the new order.

But I wouldn't recommend it.